# Entanglement entropy as the source of Bekenstein-Hawking entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, entropy, quantum-entanglement, hawking-radiation

I think I'm missing something about interpreting a black hole's entanglement entropy as the source of it's Bekenstein-Hawking entropy, and I can't find any literature on it.

So, we know that [our standard local QFTs obey entanglement entropy area laws even in flat space](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9303048) because of the short distance correlations across the entangling surface. And importantly this entanglement is spacelike, meaning it doesn't result from some causal connection between the spacetime inside and outside the given region. Thus I would think that we can apply the same logic in a black hole spacetime; if we consider even just an eternal Schwarzschild black hole, it too has these short distance correlations, and so we would expect an entanglement entropy that scales with area like any other region of spacetime.

This seems to provide good evidence that the Bekenstein-Hawking entropy reflects the entanglement entropy between the black hole and its exterior, as supported by papers such as https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9701059. The problem I see here is, how can we then think that the black hole has *any* internal degrees of freedom? How can we then think it has any differing microstates? It seems like if we interpret the entanglement entropy as the full entropy of the black hole, then the interior cannot have any further structure, as that would increase its entropy.